# Cron job on start up just wont work

Tags: cron, startup

I've been trying to make this work for over 18 hours. I'm starting to lose my mind.

I have tried making it a cronjob @reboot and a start up script

Basically I need this

```
@reboot screen -dmS minecraft
@reboot cd /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com
@reboot mono McMyAdmin.exe
```

I want to create and enter a screen then go to the directory and then mono mcmyadmin.exe

I've tried this so many ways, but it just wont work. I've asked around but no one seems to find me an exact fix.

At best I get a screen created but nothing inside of that.

The worst part is, if I enter those lines manually it works. But through a start up script or cronjob it wont.

any help PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a screen doesn't automatically run those other commands *inside* the screen (there's no reason that they should). Instead, try creating a script that you use on the `screen` command line to launch your program.

Comment: ahhh so it would create the screen then go in the screen and do the commands?

Comment: That's right. So something like: `screen -dmS minecraft /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com/start_admin` where `start_admin` is an appropriate shell script. Note also that you may need to do more setup because `mono` may or may not be available in the `PATH` that is set when `@reboot` runs.

Comment: So I tried to do it like this `screen -dmS minecraft` 
`/home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com/start.sh`
Inside start.sh I put 
`screen -S minecraft`
`mono /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com/McMyAdmin.exe`
This didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `screen -S minecraft mono home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com/McMyAdmin.exe`

this line works when I do it manually but doesn't on start up. So it seems to me mono doesn't boot up as fast as it can so it doesn't execute. I tried adding a sleep but it still didn't work